# Windows(freya) always open in background?

Tags: release-freya, window-management, gala, window-manager

Whatever app i open in elementary freya, it opens in the background.And that includes the terminal using super+T or any app from the slinghshot. I then have to click on its icon in the dock and then open it.
I searched online and saw [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1220179) ,where [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310470/newly-opened-applications-open-in-background) is suggested. I tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO this is the single most frustrating bug present in elementary OS.

Unfortunately the only realistic current fix for this bug I know about is applying [this](https://code.launchpad.net/~gala-dev/gala/always-focus-on-map/+merge/202686) patch to gala and recompiling it yourself. While the ability to do this is a testament to the power of opensource software, to avoid the headaches I have never gone down this route. It was proposed to merge the patch into gala, though seems to have been rejected on the grounds that it was a hacky workaround rather than fixing the underlying issue. Frustrating though understandable. If you attempt this (or anyone else has) it would be handy to document the steps involved somewhere and sharing with the rest of us.

There is hope however as it *appears* the problem was caused by a bug in GTK+ and [a fix](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752000) may be forthcoming. I'm unsure if the gala developers have tested this or if there is any roadmap to implement it if it does in fact work.

**Workaround**

In the meantime I have dealt with this annoyance by mapping the *multitasking view* to the upper right hand corner of my screen and gotten used to selecting windows from there. It certainly doesn't fix the problem though in hindsight this has benefited me greatly as it is a great feature which enhances my work flow. Steps to do this are outlined in [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/what-are-the-different-methods-to-switch-between-windows-and-workspaces?rq=1) answer.