# Is there a hotkey to switch through the windows of the current application? (as Alt + ` in Ubuntu)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-management

Is there any way I can replicate the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> functionality from Ubuntu?

It's like Alt + Tab only it just switches through the windows of the current application. For instance, if I have 3 file managers open and one of them focused, I can press Alt + ` to switch between the other 2 so I don't have to cycle through all other open applications

I really love elementary but this one thing is really killing my workflow. I often have multiple windows of the same application open and it's really convenient to be able to switch between them and filter out all the other open apps.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with Ubuntu, what does the `Alt` + `\`` shortcut do?

Comment: It's like Alt + Tab only it just switches through the windows of the current application. For instance, if I have 3 file managers open and one of them focused, I can press Alt + ` to switch between the other 2 so I don't have to cycle through all other open applications.

Comment: @lemonslice - I think I have to agree that it's a duplicate only ther is no answer. Or the answer is NO.

Comment: Sure, but this is a legit answer. I think if it is not possible for now, we can file a feature request on launchpad but cannot do anything here. I mean marking as a duplicate does not solve the problem, but can help put bits together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is [no such specific shortkey](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10713/170) - but it might not be needed if you consider [the range of options available](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1479/170) without trying to get exactly what you know on other desktops.

#### Especially considering the workflow:

I think Pantheon workspaces are rather intelligent in that there is no new empty workspace and any fullscreen window can get its own workspace (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>); use the shortkey that shows workspaces (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>, those can be customized) and there you can drop windows of the same application onto the empty desktop (the **+** button) to have a separate workspace for them.

[image]

You achieve the main purpose if you **use the multi-window application (and only that) in its own workspace and then switch windows there with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.** If you need more than one multi-window application, use separate workspaces for each app, and switch between apps by switching workspaces (<kbd>Super-</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

The quickest way for me is this: starting first window of my application, then <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to get a new workspace, and any new window of that app will stay in that particular workspace; if I need a new multi-window app, start the app, <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> again to get a separate workspace for that and then open the second window etc. If the fullscreen window is taken out of fullscreen (again <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>) it might go to the previous workspace but it can be easily moved as desired either by going to the workspace switcher (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>,<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>) or by using the shortkeys that move windows between workspaces.

---

#### Is it better?

This may seem complicated at first, but in fact it may prove easier than what you ask: if you had the shortkey that you mention and you used more than one multi-window applications (let's say Libreoffice Writer and Evince), that shortkey would only work for the selected application; to go from LOWriter to Evince you would either use the mouse or set separate workspaces for the different apps in the first place, in which case your ubuntu shortkey is useless.

I think this is just a matter of using workspaces or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. I think this is a decent way to go about what I'm looking for in the meantime but I'd still like to see something like Alt + ` implemented. I guess I'll just need to learn Vala :)

Comment: @Haronious - I think that workspaces serve no other purpose than grouping windows.