# Switch only between windows of the same application (not tabs)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-management, window-manager

I would like to be able to switch between the open windows of one application by using (or assigning first) a shortcut (like I do in Ubuntu, Linux Mint and MacOS).

I have often more than one window open of one application like chrome or an IDE and I want to quickly move between them.
Yes I know I can move the mouse over the icon and scroll or right click, but this involves taking my hands of the keyboard. I want a keyboard shortcut like in all the other OS I'm using.

Yes I know of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and workspaces but this is no real substitute for such a basic functionality.
I couldn't find the corresponding action under Keyboard-->Shortcuts-->Windows; is it seems missing?

**I also don't mean <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/PageDn</kbd>.**

(In Ubuntu, Linux Mint and MacOS the shortcut I'm refering to is taken care by the window manager while the proposed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/PageDn</kbd> has to be implemented by the application itself.)

The behavior is not consistent and often missing. For example **in Chrome this shortcut switches between Tabs and not Windows**. And for elementary built in apps like Terminal or Files it is not implemented. In this list of shortcuts [here](http://lmelinux.net/2014/07/26/elementary-os-keyboard-shortcuts/) the shortcut I'm looking for is not mentioned.

Does anyone know maybe the underlying system command so I can create custom shortcut? Or hot to configure xbindkeys to allow window switching?
Or is this functionality completely missing from elementary?

---

Edit:
Cipricus created a great answer here: [How does one cycle through windows of the same application?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/how-does-one-cycle-through-windows-of-the-same-application)

And it seems the functionality is missing while in Ubuntu it's available.
See : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sewJD.jpg
The shortcut in Ubuntu ist <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>GRAVE</kbd>

I know Plank can do it by scrolling so is there any way I can use that to create a shortcut to switch the windows? Where could I request that feature?

I know that elementary has all the nice workspaces to organize your work but I feel that is a very basic functionality missing here. MacOS also has a similar workspace organization and there the shortcut exists without problems and I make heavy use of it.

---

#### Edit about closing this as duplicate:

[How does one cycle through windows of the same application?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4844/170) seems to ask the same thing but its [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4861/170) is the one tested and not working as indicated above:  **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/PageDn</kbd> is not working**. - Also, the [source](http://lmelinux.net/2014/07/26/elementary-os-keyboard-shortcuts/) posted for that is not confirming it: it does not mention such a shortkey at all!

[What are the different methods to switch between windows and workspaces?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1441/170) - asks precisely this at its first point, that is: **between windows of the same application on the same workspace** (implying of course 'only between those of the same application'; without that implication, cycling **all** windows will eventually cycle those of the application that has multiple windows open: but that's not the point). - Anyway, Daniel Foré's [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1479/170) marked as definitive gives a lot of details but **doesn't answer the first point**.

Comment: @lemonslice - I have edited the linked question to make it clearly say `windows of the same application`. The above seems a duplicate, but is the answer below the linked one really working? - e.g. for Evince? - I cannot confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes while searching I have found both of these threads, but none of them answer my question. My main point here is that this functionality is available in Ubuntu but it seems to be missing from elementary. Is the actual functionality missing in elemtary's desktop manager or is it just not available through the shortcut menu?

Comment: I was looking for the same option so I started looking into this on this site; it was already posted multiple times, I think four times in total, beside yours and the ones mentioned above there is also [this one](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10394/170). I have tried to clarify the issue by posting an answer that basically says that there is no such option and it's unlikely it will be implemented as the same purpose (of cycling windows of a single app) is served by putting them all in a separate workspace and then using the already present Alt-Tab. I will post an answer here too.

Comment: please use `@` before a username to send your comment to that user

Comment: Considering my answer: imagine you have two or more applications with multiple windows (e.g. LOWriter and Evince) that you have to use at the same time, that shortcut would not be enough. Separating such windows in groups by separate workspaces seems much cleaner. In this way you can keep many windows of the same app open but cycle only *some* of them if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option that you could use with a keyboard shortcut -- and probably it will not be implemented: workspaces serve precisely the purpose of grouping windows.

If the multiple windows of the same application are on the same workspace, the goal is achieved with the shortcut for switching windows of the same workspace (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>) **if only that application is using that workspace**.

The general idea is to **open the multi-window application (and only that) in its own workspace and then switch windows there with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.**

Go to the Workspace Switcher (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>,<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>) and there you can add new workspace and drag&drop windows between workspaces; namely, drop the windows of your application onto the **+** button to add to new workspace.

[image]

If you need more than one multi-window application, use separate workspaces for each app, and switch between apps by switching workspaces (<kbd>Super-</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Note also that any window that is made fullscreen with <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> gets a new workspace for itself.